# Any Alternatives of directly checking if any of the services has stopped?

Tags: c#, windows-services

Because the Win32_Service class does not have a corresponding WMI event provider, the WITHIN keyword must be used to signify that the WMI polling mechanism should be used with a polling interval,using it to monitor if any of the services has stopped would be expensive (CPU,Resources).

Other than using ProcessStopTrace class,

(1) any indications of "service stopped" in registry?

(2) any other way of directly checking if services have stopped?

(3) There are Notify Routines in Windows, are they applicable here?

Sincerely

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class, which includes a static method to return all services as well as the ability to get details on individual services.

I don't know of any built-in mechanism that will trigger an event on a status change.

Comment: Even if you are using the Win32 API, you have to poll to determine when a service stops. Even if a .NET class were to trigger an event on a service stopping, behind the scenes it would be polling anyway.